# "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" using scipy.optimize in Sage

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sage

I want to adjust the parameters of a model to a given set of data.

I'm trying to use `scipy`'s function `curve_fit` in Sage, but I keep getting

`TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Here´s my code:

```
from numpy import cos,exp,pi
f = lambda x: exp(  - 1 / cos(x)  )
import numpy as np

def ang(time): return (time-12)*pi/12

def temp(x,maxtemp):
    cte=(273+maxtemp)/f(0)**(1/4)
    if 6<x and x<18:
        return float(cte*f(ang(x))**(1/4)-273)
    else:
        return -273

lT=list(np.linspace(15,40,1+24*2))
lT=[float(num) for num in lT]             #list of y data

ltimes=np.linspace(0,24,6*24+1)[1:]
ltimes=list(ltimes)                     #list of x data
u0=lT[0]

def u(time,maxtemp,k):                    #the function I want to fit to the data
    def integ(t): return k*exp(k*t)*temp(t,maxtemp)
    return exp(-k*time)*( numerical_integral(integ, 0, time)[0] + u0 )

import scipy.optimize as optimization

print optimization.curve_fit(u, ltimes, lT,[1000,0.0003])
```

Comment: Try putting the parameters in a tuple rather than list: `optimization.curve_fit(u, ltimes, lT,(1000,0.0003))`

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have a suggestion that would improve your chance of getting an answer: reduce the size of the code to the part that's actually relevant. [Here is my example](https://gist.github.com/normalhuman/2b3778eb4660a7cfa258): it's just 4 lines, reproducing the same issue.  More people are willing to consider 4 lines of code than 20, where most are irrelevant.

Comment: What is `numerical_integral` and what does it return.

Comment: `numerical_integral` returns a tuple of the answer and an error estimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scipy.optimize.curve_fit` expects the model function to be *vectorized*: that is, it must be able to receive an array (ndarray, to be precise), and return an array of values. You can see the problem right away by adding a debug printout

```
def u(time,maxtemp,k):                    
    print time                % for debugging
    def integ(t): return k*exp(k*t)*temp(t,maxtemp)
    return exp(-k*time)*( numerical_integral(integ, 0, time)[0] + u0 )
```

The output of print will be the entire array `ltimes` you are passing to `curve_fit`.   This is something `numerical_integral` is not designed to handle. You need to give it values one by one.

Like this:

```
def u(time,maxtemp,k):                    
    def integ(t): return k*exp(k*t)*temp(t,maxtemp)
    return [exp(-k*time_i)*( numerical_integral(integ, 0, time_i)[0] + u0) for time_i in time]
```

This will take care of the “only length-1 arrays can be converted" error. You will then have another one, because your lists ltimes and lT are of different length, which doesn't make sense since lT is supposed to be the target outputs for inputs ltimes. You should revise the definitions of these arrays to figure out what size you want.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer to this exact question, but if you use *math* library in your function it will cause this error, as they are not designed to handle arrays. So just use *numpy* functions instead.

For example:

```
def predictor(x,a,b):
    return math.exp(a+b*x)
```

Should be changed to:

```
def predictor(x,a,b):
    return numpy.exp(a+b*x)
```